# Hard Drive Pertition Not Showing

Tags: hard-drive

I am Wahid,user of ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Before install it I was install Windows 10 in my pc. Before install Windows 10 I was create a pertition from windows cd on "C Drive" [8 GB Capacity]. I went to install ubuntu 14.04 LTS on the new 8GB pertition. I was intalling it for first time from a cd. After install it I see there is no disc of my hard drive on the homepage.I am totaly unable to use my hard disc.

In this circumstance I want to know that where is my old data [like "D Drive","E Drive","F Drive"] ? How can I detect & recover my hard disc.   Please help me.....There is the most importat data in my life in the hard disc.

Comment: Can you boot into Windows or Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

By right ntfs support are installed by default during installation. However if the support was missing (ie Deleted after installation). You can perform below steps to get it back.

Windows using different filesystem from Linux ie. NTFS. To make Windows partition visible in Linux you need to install ntfs-3g.

1. Go into terminal `Ctrl + Alt + T`.
2. Type `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`
3. Then look for ntfs partion. `fdisk -l`
4. Mount it.

Worse case is during the partition creation, your windows drive was deleted. That will explain why you cant see it anymore.

Comment: It is installed by default. And it may cause harm if the Windows partitions have been deleted.

Comment: @Pilot6 correct, i have edited the answer.

Comment: I am sure the problem is not related to `ntfs-3g`.

Comment: @Pilot6, exacty, if the partition is there he can see it from the right panel when Ubuntu booted. Btw, since i have adjusted the answer, shall you remove the down vote on it.

Comment: I suggest you delete the answer until we get information from OP. Most likely the partition is not there. So it is better not to install anything that can overwrite the important data.

Comment: Installing ntfs-3g wont break anything.  It just kernel module and shared library.